# Errno::ENOTDIR (Not a directory @ rb_sysopen

Tags: ruby

This is the code:

```
File.read(File.expand_path("data.json", __FILE__))
```

This is the error I get:

```
Errno::ENOTDIR (Not a directory @ rb_sysopen - /mnt/c/Users/Amadeus Pagel/Documents/readpaths/imports/khanacademy/import.rb/data.json)
```

But when I run this from the rails console in the readpaths directory it works:

```
File.read("imports/khanacademy/data.json")
```

Comment: You are trying to read the file `/mnt/c/Users/Amadeus Pagel/Documents/readpaths/imports/khanacademy/import.rb/data.json` The operating system is telling you that this path doesn't exist. Usually, the operating system is right. Unfortunately, the information in your question is incomplete, in particular, it is important to know: does this path exist or not?

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to File.expand_path should be a directory, but you are passing `__FILE__`, which is a file, not a directory. You either need to use `File.dirname(__FILE__)` or `__dir__`.

Answer (score 0):

*FILE* gives the relative path of current file which in your case is 
**/mnt/c/Users/Amadeus Pagel/Documents/readpaths/imports/khanacademy/import.rb** 
import.rb is not a  directory. So, you are getting error. Try this

**File.read(File.expand_path("data.json",File.dirname(__FILE__))**

Comment: What is the advantage of using `File.dirname(__FILE__)` over just [`__dir__`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-__dir__)?